# How to count percentage match between textbox and datagridview cell after search

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Im trying to make search to show percentage match between textbox and datagridview column cell content, for example if i type billy in textbox this should compare billy to all results in datagridview "name" column and calculate percentage match and show it on label.

example

textbox = billy

"name" column has many names like bob,billy,brand...

match percentage should be low on bob and it should be 100 on billy.

Comment: Why should 'Billy' match percentage be 100? If your datagrid contains more than 1 name then no value should give a 100% match.

Comment: You want a percentage for each cell as to how well it matches. You need to establish some ground rules. One letter match would be a certain percentage. For a five letter word, maybe 20%. How about Bob and Bobbett? Is this a 100% match or is it counted down for extra letters? Think this trough then try some code based on your decisions. I think a start would be putting the name into a char array. Then you could compare letter by letter.

Comment: @Mary thats exactly what i want to do but dunno how to do that it would be great if you showed me some exampe

Comment: @Luka Well, I would have to know what you "dunno." Do you know how to loop through the data in your grid? Do you know how to use Substring? Have you decided what to do with your results? Are you comfortable with For loops?

Comment: @Mary I dont know all listed above

Comment: @Luka Please do a search on the internet for VB.Net beginner. Microsoft has a free course and there are many tutorials. If this is a school project, make sure you are stating the requirements correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index;
if (DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[index].Value == textBox1.text)
{
    //do something
}
```

or

```
if (DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells["ColumnName"].Value == textBox1.text)
{
    //do something
}
```